# How to solve $n\log_2(n) = C$?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, lambert-w

I am trying to solve the following equation:

$$
n\log_2(n) = C
$$
with $C$ being a constant greater than $0$.

I thought about putting the $n$ that is outside the $\log$ on the power of the $n$ inside but that is surely not the way. I also thought about exponentiating everything but I can't see how that is going to help.

Can I please get some help?
Thanks

Comment: Write it as $n\log n = C \log2$ and use the Lambert $W$-function: $n=e^{W(C\log 2)}$.

Comment: Ok, so $n^n=2^C$... Now try with different values of $n$ which are powers of $2$... One is $n=C=2$, another one is $n=4$, $C=8$ and so on... Observe a pattern from this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w = \log n$, $e^w = n$. Then $$we^w = C\log 2$$so that $w = W(C\log 2)$ where $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function, that is $n = \exp(W(C\log 2))$.

Comment: Thanks, So I just need to use the lambert W function and that's it? is there a proof or something, I am curious at how the result came up

Comment: @lalaland Just use the definition of the Lambert $W$-function.